# Array value into "SELECT ...."

Tags: mysql, arrays, escaping, concatenation, quotes

I has this var of a query and I want to know if there is any alternative to the quotes in LIKE '".$producto['product_reference']."'

```
$producto_color = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS(
                    "SELECT `name` 
                    FROM `jd_attribute_lang` 
                    WHERE `id_attribute` 
                    IN (
                        SELECT `id_attribute` 
                        FROM `jd_product_attribute_combination` 
                        WHERE `id_product_attribute` 
                        IN (
                            SELECT `id_product_attribute` 
                            FROM `jd_product_attribute` 
                            WHERE `reference`
                            LIKE '".$producto['product_reference']."'
                            )
                        )
                    AND `id_attribute` 
                    IN(
                        SELECT `id_attribute`
                        FROM `jd_attribute` 
                        WHERE `id_attribute_group` LIKE 2
                        OR `id_attribute_group` LIKE 5
                        OR `id_attribute_group` LIKE 9
                        OR `id_attribute_group` LIKE 10
                        OR `id_attribute_group` LIKE 11
                        OR `id_attribute_group` LIKE 12
                        OR `id_attribute_group` LIKE 16
                        OR `id_attribute_group` LIKE 19
                        OR `id_attribute_group` LIKE 20
                        ) 
                    AND `id_lang` = $id_language"
                );
```

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

The alternative to that style of writing it in php would be a line such as this:

```
LIKE #{$producto['product_reference']}
```

This style does not make you end the quotation marks which I find a lot more convenient when I am typing out long PHP strings. The dot notation where you have to end the quotation marks is occasionally more convenient in a shorter string but in a longer one such as this I prefer this way of inserting variables.